# Bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{(X,Y), X\subset Y\subset \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does anyone know how to construct a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{(X,Y), X\subset Y\subset \mathbb{N}\}$?($\subset$ means "lies in or equals to")

I'll  appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(X,Y)\ $  means Cartesian product ?

Comment: Yes, it's Cartesian product.

Comment: Do you search a bijection to the product of the sets or to the elements of the products of sets ?

Comment: I'd guess he means $(X,Y)$ is the pair of the sets $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Between all pairs $(X,Y)$,defined upper,where $X \subset Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that I'm assuming in the following that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ (because I think that way it's a bit easier to write the bijection). Of course adjusting for $0\in N$ is trivial.

**Step 1:** Define a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to the interval $(0,1)$. This is easy, e.g
$$ f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm e^x} $$

**Step 2:** Define a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$ by the function
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n-1} & x=\frac1n, n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

**Step 3:** For each number $y\in(0,1]$, take the ternary expansion. Always choose the expansion which ends in "$222\ldots$" instead of "$000\ldots$".
Now define
$$g(y) = (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{X} &= \{n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{The $n$-th digit of the ternary representation of $y$ is $2$}\}\\
\mathcal{Y} &= \{n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{The $n$-th digit of the ternary representation of $y$ is not $0$}\}
\end{align}$$
Quite obviously $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathcal{Y}\subset{N}$. However, by construction, we only get infinite $\mathcal{Y}$ (because finite $\mathcal{Y}$ would correspond to a ternary expansion ending in period $0$). On the other hand, all pairs of arbitrary $\mathcal{X}$ and infinite $\mathcal{Y}$ with $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathcal{Y}$ uniquely define an $y\in(0,1]$.

Proof that $g$ is bijective:

For any $y\in (0,1]$, there's (thanks to the disambiguation rule to never take the periodic 0 representation) exactly one ternary representation, and each such representation there's exactly one $y$.

The sets $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ encode exactly the sequence of digits (digit $n$ is $0$ iff $n\notin\mathcal{Y}$, digit $n$ is $1$ iff $n\in\mathcal{Y}\setminus\mathcal{X}$, digit $n$ is $2$ iff $n\in\mathcal{X}$). As long as $\mathcal{Y}$ is infinite, the corresponding ternary representation will not be finite (end in period $0$), and vice versa. Thus we have an one-to-one mapping between the set pairs with infinite $\mathcal{Y}$ and the infinite ternary representations, and thus the real numbers in the interval $(0,1]$.

**Step 4:** Now all that's left is to map the pairs of sets with the subset property where $\mathcal{Y}$ is infinite to the set of pairs of possibly finite sets with the inclusion property.

This bijection from the set of all pairs to the set of infinite pairs (note: that's the opposite direction we need, but I think it's easier to write down than the reverse) is given by
$$h(X,Y) =
\begin{cases}
(X,Y) & \text{neither $Y$ nor $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ is finite}\\
(X+1,Y+1) & \text{$\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ is finite}\\
\left(\{1\}\cup\left((\mathbb{N}\setminus Y)+1\right),\{1\}\cup\left((\mathbb{N}\setminus X)+1\right)\right) & \text{Y is finite}
\end{cases}$$
Here $X+1 = \{n+1: n\in X\}$.

The complete bijection is therefore $h^{-1}\circ g\circ F\circ f$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't give an "explicit" bijection. What you can do is showing that your set $S=\{(X,Y):X\subset Y\subset \mathbb{N}\}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is known to be equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$.

You have an obvious injection $S\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, so that $|S|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\times\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$.

You have also an injection $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to S$, defined by $Y\mapsto(\emptyset,Y)$, so $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|\le|S|$.

Showing an explicit bijection $S\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\times\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ would already be quite complicated, but the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem gives the conclusion.

Some slight modifications are needed if with $\subset$ you mean “strict inclusion”.

Comment: Even though I have the feeling that an explicit bijection will be pretty hard to find, I don't see an arguement in your answer that an explicit bijection is not constructable. For Example for Cantor Bernstein one doesn't even need Axiom of Choice

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But I need an explicit bijection. Something like Cantor's numbering.

Comment: @Alex why do you need an explicit bijection ?

Comment: Because my teacher is not satisfied with Cantor-Bernstein theorem approach and he demands the explicit bijection. But if it's really  hard, maybe I convince him with it.

Comment: @Alex It's *impossible* to write an explicit bijection in a first order formula. C-S-B is how far one can go.

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis Sorry, I'm new to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @egreg Ok, thanks!

Comment: @egreg: If it's impossible, where's the error in my post?

Comment: @celtschk Are you sure that $g$ is bijective? I'm not.

Comment: I've just noticed one problem, namely that you need to include $y=1$ for $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$. But that is easily fixed by another intermediate mapping step. But other than that, the mapping is indeed bijective (note that I explicitly avoided the period 0/period 2 ambiguities in the ternary representation). I'll fix the "endpoint issue" and add a short bijectivity proof for $g$.

Comment: Oops, I've just noticed another problem ... but I think that can be fixed as well. Stay tuned :-)

Comment: @egreg: OK, I think I now fixed all problems. And it turned out that my $h$ would have been wrong if the previously claimed properties for $g$ had held, but is exactly right for the actual properties of $g$. :-) Please have a look if I overlooked anything else.